# unable to make table in markdown format

Tags: github, markdown

https://github.com/ishan-nitj/Competitve-Programming/blob/master/TODO%20PROBLEMS.md

I have made a table in md format but it is not displaying at github.However same is working at a markdown editor:[link](https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Github directly : [Organizing information with tables](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/)

> There must be at least three hyphens in each column of the header row.

Your first header row only has one hyphen.

You also have to put an empty line on top of your table, like this :

```
Date:17 September  2016

|SNO|LEVEL|NAME|COMMENTS|DONE ON|
|---|---------------|--------------|----------|----|
1|DIV2 E|[Pashmak and Graph|(http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/459/E)|Tried but getting WA
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: even now it is not working.[link](https://github.com/ishan-nitj/Competitve-Programming/blob/master/TODO%20PROBLEMS.md)